I want to predict stock price in next 60 days by machine learning
I wanted to predict stock price in the next 60 days but after I finished writing the code, it predicted backward instead. Can anyone advise me? How can I do it? I revised my code but it's not working.
My code is
import math
from mplfinance.original_flavor import candlestick_ohlc
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error


Tencent2.head()
#Define the features and target
##features = ['Open', 'Vol.']
##target = 'Price'


#Plot line chart
Tencent2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Tencent2['Date'])
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
plt.plot(Tencent2['Date'], Tencent2['Close'], marker='.')
plt.title('Close by Month', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=13)
plt.ylabel('Close', fontsize=13)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()


#Plot Candle Chart
matplotlib_date = mdates.date2num(Tencent2['Date'])
ohlc = np.vstack((matplotlib_date,Tencent2['Open'],Tencent2['High'],Tencent2['Low'],Tencent2['Close'])).T
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
ax = plt.subplot()
candlestick_ohlc(ax,ohlc,width=0.8,colorup='g',colordown='r')
ax.xaxis_date()
plt.title('Movement of Close Price')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


#Resetting the index
Tencent2.set_index('Date', inplace=True)


#Create a new dataframe with only the 'Close' column
data = Tencent2.filter(['Close'])


#Convert the dataframe to a numpy array
dataset = data.values
#Get the number of rows to train the model on
training_data = math.ceil( len(dataset) * 0.7 )


#Scale the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)


#Create the training data set 
#Create the scaled training data set
train_data = scaled_data[0:training_data, :]
#Split the data into x_train and y_train data sets
x_train = []
y_train = []
#We create a loop
for i in range(60, len(train_data)):
  x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i, 0]) 
  y_train.append(train_data[i, 0]) 
  if i <= 60:
    print(x_train)
    print(y_train)
    print()


#Convert the x_train and y_train to numpy arrays
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)


#Reshape the data
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
x_train.shape


#Build the LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(25))
model.add(Dense(1))


#Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')


#Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=1)


#Create the testing data set
#Create a new array containing scaled values from index 1738 to 2247
test_data = scaled_data[training_data - 60:]
#Create the data set X_test and y_test
X_test = []
y_test = dataset[training_data:, :]
for i in range(60, len(test_data)):
  X_test.append(test_data[i-60:i, 0])


#Convert the data to a numpy array
X_test = np.array(X_test)


#Reshape the data
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))


#Get the model's predicted price values for the X_test data set
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = scaler.inverse_transform(predictions)


#Evaluate model (get the root mean quared error (RMSE))
rmse = np.sqrt( np.mean( predictions - y_test )**2 )


#Plot the data
train = data[:training_data]
valid = data[training_data:]
valid['Predictions'] = predictions
#Visualize the data
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title('Model')
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Close Price', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(train['Close'])
plt.plot(valid[['Close', 'Predictions']])
plt.legend(['Train', 'Validation', 'Predictions'], loc='lower right')
plt.show()


I want to predict the price 60 days into the future, but the price is predicted in the past. How can I predict the price after 2024-06?
Thank you for your help.

"but the price is predicted in the past"? What do you mean? Also read this

You can see my line graph. It shows data in backward but I want to predict data after 2024-06

curious, was it accurate for historical prices ? (you might be on to something if so) ?

I export this dataset from the stock price website and want to predict future prices not historical prices.

Now I can fix this problem, which comes from the date being formatted incorrectly. I change my code as below
Tencent2 = Tencent[['Date','Close']]
Tencent2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(Tencent['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')
Tencent2['Close'] = Tencent2['Close'].astype(float)
#Resetting the index
Tencent2 = Tencent2.set_index('Date')    #Setting the Date as Index
Tencent2.sort_index(inplace=True)


ax = Tencent2.plot(figsize=(15, 9))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b-%Y'))
ax.xaxis.labelpad = 10
ax.tick_params(axis='x',labelrotation=40)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Close', fontsize=12)
plt.title("Closing price distribution of Tencent", fontsize=15)
plt.plot(Tencent2, color='green', linewidth = 2)
plt.show()

